# How to compute the Jacobian of diffusive flux?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, fluid-statics

In the conservation form of the shallow water system
$$ \dfrac{\partial h}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial q}{\partial x}=0$$
$$ \dfrac{\partial q}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}(\dfrac{q^2}{h}+\dfrac{g h^2}{2})=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}(\nu h\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x})-gh(S_{z}+S_{f}) $$
where $$ (h,q)=(h, hu) \text{ = the height and the momentum }$$
The jacobian matrix of convective flux is $$ \begin{pmatrix} 0& 1\\ g h-\dfrac{q^2}{h^2} &\dfrac{2 q}{h}\end{pmatrix}$$
Assuming the viscosity is constant and the diffusive term will be written as
$$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}(\nu h\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x})=\nu\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}(\dfrac{\partial q}{\partial x}-
\dfrac{q}{h}\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x})$$
If possible, I want to find the jacobian matrix of the diffusive flux.

Is it correct that the diffusive jacobian will be written as
$$\nu \begin{pmatrix} 0& 0\\ \dfrac{q}{h^2} \dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x}&-\dfrac{1}{h}\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x}\end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: Why do you need it? In numerical methods, for conservation laws, one usually only needs the Jacobian (exact or approxiamated) of the convective terms to get the information about the direction and the velocity of the propagation of information in the medium

Comment: I am studying viscous fluids and how to treat diffusive terms numerically.